# MySql Query : How to select data which is not exist in last 90 days from the given date value?

Tags: mysql, select-query

I have one "User" table with fields UserId and addedDate.

I need to get data of users - added in the last month and current month and not in system for 90 days prior to **added** **date**.

User Table

```
Userid      addedDate         enddate
001        2017-07-01       2017-09-05
002        2017-02-25       2017-02-01
003        2017-06-01       2017-09-21
003        2017-04-25       2017-05-29
004        2017-06-01       2017-09-21  
005        2017-06-05       2017-09-07
005        2017-01-01       2017-01-31
```

I need output like :

```
userid
  001
  004
  005
```

Here 003 is not required as its not a new user(as its available system for 90 days prior to **added** **date**). and 002 is not added in last moth or current moth, so this also cant consider as new user.

I have tried below query but its not working fine :

```
select userid from usertbl final
WHERE final.userid NOT IN (
SELECT meb.userid 
FROM usertbl meb 
INNER JOIN 
( 
SELECT mc.userid, addeddate, enddate 
FROM usertbl mc 
WHERE mc.enddate > NOW() 
AND mc.addeddate > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -90 DAY) 
) s 
ON s.userid = meb.userid 
AND 
(
meb.enddate > DATE_ADD(s.addeddate,INTERVAL -90 DAY) 
AND meb.enddate <> s.enddate
) 
)
```

Please provide some suggestions.

Comment: Btw, this is off-topic.

Comment: @tilz0R Why should it be? I see sample data, desired result and even an explanation and the query OP has tried. Actually this is a sql question how it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `INNER` query to get the results:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE addedDate >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)
AND userid NOT IN (
    SELECT userid 
    FROM users
    WHERE addedDate < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)
);
```

A couple of points:

- Userid `003` is **not** available 90 days prior to `addedDate` in the system (2017-06-01 vs 2017-04-25, that is 37 days), so it's probably same as selection criteria (i.e. not this month or last month)?
- Userid `005` is available  90 days (or last month) prior to `addedDate` so it should not be picked up as well

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9f9c3/1/0)**.

Comment: Hey Darshan... thanks for the solution, but in sub query you have given addedDate < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH). I need to check Userid is not available 90 days prior to "addedDate" in the system  not from now(). So i need to put self join over there.